# Avoiding duplicate jars in a war file

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3, war

I have Jar named A.jar which has dependencies of some jars like A1.jar,A2.jar and A3.jar. Now mentioning those dependencies in pom and i have builded the jar file.
Now the war file B1.war has dependency on A.jar. so i have mentioned the same in war's pom, generated the war and it works fine. The issue is under the lib folder of B.war, A.jar is available. And also A1.jar, A2.jar and A3,jar is also available(ie duplicaated). how to avoid this ?

Comment: It's not duplicated. A.jar relies on A1.jar, A2.jar and A3.jar. They're not bundled inside A.jar. But to make sure A.jar has all its dependencies to function, B.war pulls in everything A.jar needs.

Comment: @Jaims A1.jar, A2.jar and A3.jar are bundled in A.jar. but still A1.jar , A2.jar and A3.jar are available in B.war . (ie) the lib folder of A.jar has A1.jar A2.jar and A3.jar. the lib folder of B.war contains A.jar , A1.jar , A2.jar and A3.jar. I dont want A1.jar , A2.jar and A3.jar in B.war. I want them only in A.jar's lib folder.

Comment: any update on this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all you can see the dependecies of a jar in Pom->Dependency
  hierarchy.
- Second, If you are using jboss, maybe some dependencies    are
  already in jboss, so try to use 
  `< scope >provided < /scope>` in your dependecies(so it will take only the 
  dependecies that are not in jboss).
- Third, if the second point is useless, try to add ,in your dependencies
  that have other dependecies :

  > < exclusions>
  >   < groupId >org.slf4j< /groupId >
  >   < artifactId> slf4j-log4j12 < /artifactId >
  >   < /exclusion>